# 2 empty pages in the beginning of my Latex paper

Tags: pdftex

Using the following packages and settings, two empty pages resulted in the beginning of my paper, the paper including the title is started from the third page. In the first page, I have just "1.5em 0pt". How can I remove the two empty pages?

```
%\documentclass[8pt]{llncs}
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper,fleqn]{llncs}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english,turkey]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfiles}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
%\usepackage{amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[belowskip=-1pt,aboveskip=0pt]{mathtools}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlist{nosep} 

%\usepackage[ruled,noend]{algorithm2e} %to put 2 algorithm side by side
%for space of refernces%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\setlength{\bibsep}{-3pt} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,skip=-8pt, belowskip=0pt,aboveskip=1pt]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\sloppy

\DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{6}{6}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand\fplus{\mathrel+}

%% Save the class definition of \subparagraph
\let\llncssubparagraph\subparagraph
%% Provide a definition to \subparagraph to keep titlesec happy
\let\subparagraph\paragraph
%% Load titlesec
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
%% Revert \subparagraph to the llncs definition
\let\subparagraph\llncssubparagraph
\titlespacing\section {0pt} {12pt plus 0pt minus 2pt} {0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection {0pt} {0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt} {0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection {0pt} {0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt} {0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english,turkey]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
%\usepackage{amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\setlist{nosep} 
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx


\sloppy

\DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{6}{6}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%\setlength\floatsep{10 pt}
%\setlength\textfloatsep{7.5 pt}
%\setlength\intextsep{7.5 pt}

%\doi{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
%\isbn{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
%\conferenceinfo{PLDI '13}{June 16--19, 2013, Seattle, WA, USA}

%\acmPrice{\$15.00}

%\conferenceinfo{WOODSTOCK}{'97 El Paso, Texas USA}

%space of equations
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
}
\makeatother
%psace of section titles


\begin{document}


\mainmatter 
% first the title is needed
\title{}
\author{}


\maketitle
```

Comment: Creating a [mcve] will show you exactly where/why that happens...

Comment: Well, this example is of course not compilable at all! It contains a huge bunch of packages probably not needed and the most relevant code, that causes the problem is not shown, i.e. the content right after `\begin{document}`

Comment: why load color four times, amsmath twice, graphicx four times etc etc, do you _really_ use all those packages in one document?

Comment: `algpseudocode` must be a very important package, if you load it 5 times.

Comment: @samcarter more important than my packages. Hhmph I'm offended now:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that [`algpseudocode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) and [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) are not compatible, as illustrated by the following *minimal* example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

For this specific reason, if you wish to use `algorithmic`-like input, the `algorithmicx` bundle provides the `algcompatible` package. From the [`algorithmicx` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) (section **2.1 The package**):

> **`algcompatible`** is fully compatible with the `algorithmic` package, it should be used only in old documents

You should therefore avoid loading both `algpseudocode` *and* `algorithmic`, but instead just load `algcompatible` *or* `algorithmic`.

Comment: Following [@Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner)'s comment, it is also possible to combine ```algorithm``` and ```algpseudocode```.

Answer (score 2):

After doing disable of \usepackage{algorithmic} and enable of \usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}, the problem of showing "1.5em 0pt" at the First blank page is solved now. Tahnks all